# Trying to run an "if" statement in R. Want to run a chunk of code on if my variable is a certain value

Tags: r, if-statement

I want to run a chunk of code on if my variable values is "1099".

Further up the code I assign a value to a variable called "Phone Code" i.e.,

```
Phone Code <- "1099"
```

I want to run a chunk only if this value is "1099". Sometimes I run the code and use the value 1098 which means I don't want that specific code to run.

Currently I have tried the following:

```
if (Phone Code <- "1099"){

CODE HERE

}
```

Comment: And what is your question about this?

Comment: Maybe some beginner R tutorials would be helpful first to learn the difference between `<-`, `=`, and `==`.  `<-` is for assignment, not equality. I liked [this site](https://www.statmethods.net/) when I was first learning R

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the following.

```
if (Phone Code == "1099"){

CODE HERE

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the if_else() function from the tidyverse package.

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- c(-5:5, NA)

if_else(x < 0, NA_integer_, x)
#>  [1] NA NA NA NA NA  0  1  2  3  4  5 NA

if_else(x < 0, "negative", "positive", "missing")
#>  [1] "negative" "negative" "negative" "negative" "negative" "positive"
#>  [7] "positive" "positive" "positive" "positive" "positive" "missing"
```

Example taken from [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/if_else.html).

Comment: `if_else` is from `dplyr`, and is just a stricter version of base `ifelse`; no need to load the entire set of tidyverse packages for that one function. It also doesn't seem like this addresses the specific question, which was about how to compare 2 values

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer from another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69074080/18304077)

In your case, it would look like

```
{r "my chunk name", eval = (Phone Code == "1099")}

>code goes here
```

NB object names should not have spaces- and are *case sensitive*- so i'd suggest you use "phonecode" for ease.