# How to run a chunk in R only if a variable is present in the environment? Otherwise skip to next chunk

Tags: r, dataframe, function, r-markdown

I have a part of my RMD file that only needs to be run if a data frame is present in the environment.

So say I only need to run part of the code if data frame "Data_X" is present in the environment. Otherwise I want it to skip that chunk and go on to the next one.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3):

````
```{r eval = exists(yourDataFrameName)}
print("The chunk is evaluated since yourDataFrameName exists")
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Start your chunk with

```
if ( exists ( yourDataFrameName ) ) {
# put the chunk here



}
```